Multiple sub-questions per question
I've recently seen many questions posted with multiple sub-questions. For example, see Understanding x86 C main function preamble created by Visual C++ - while sub-questions 2, 3, and 4 are related, sub-question 1 is not. Another example is What changes in MS Windows system libraries after restart?
Can we please update https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/asking to suggest that people only ask one question per post?

Sometimes, this is ok: if the asker isn't essentially breaking down one reasonably-scoped question into smaller pieces as a way of organizing his thoughts. 
But if some or all of the sub-questions aren't very closely, then you should consider editing the question to reflect just the ones that are (even if this is only one of them), and encouraging him to ask more once he has an answer. 
